# Mapsforge add button to Mapview

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, mapsforge

I am working on an Android App for skier and snowboarder which should navigate the user from one point to another.

To show the map I am using Mapsforge-Version 0.4.0.

On the map I have added some layers and now I want to add an Imagebutton but all attempts failed. Do you have some ideas how to do that without an Xml-File?

I am new and it is my first question, so if I have forget some information please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

STEP 1 : avoid setting content view to mapView

```
   // setContentView(mapView);
```

STEP 2 : 
add your button to a linearlayout
simply add your linearlayout to a relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlMap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llControls"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

STEP 3 : Find your RelativeLayout and add your mapView Object to it

```
RelativeLayout rlMap = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMap);
rlMap.addView(mapView,0);
```